# advantage of select-before-update in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

To avoid UPDATE statement while reattaching an object is through setting the select-before-update= “true”. If this is set, hibernates tries to determine whether UPDATE needed, by executing the SELECT statement.
But what is the advantage of such feature, cause after all we are hitting db either through SELECT or through UPDATE.

Comment: There are scenarios where you want to avoid an `UPDATE` if unnecessary.

Comment: but in that case we shoot a select query to avoid unnecessary UPDATEs. please provide one scenario, could be helpful.

Comment: There may be triggers which logs who made the update for example. You don't want those to run if the user didn't actually update anything.